# selecting distinct elements from two lists using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<int> lst1 = new List<int>{1,2,3,5,2};
List<int> lst2 = new List<int>{4,5,6,1,6};
List<int> lst3 = new List<int>();
```

> **Expected Output:** lst3={1,2,3,4,5,6}

Can anyone help me with the  LINQ code to select distinct elements from two lists ?

*Thank you*

Comment: What code are you using right now, and what outputs are you getting? Show us what you've tried before asking us to work for you.

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. Am just new to C#. i have tried using joins.
This is wat i did
var z = from x in n join y in m on true equals true select (x);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, you can do

```
lst1.AddRange(lst2);
List<int> lst3  = lst1.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 16):

Use the [`Union()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341731(v=vs.100).aspx) method, which produces the Set Union of two lists, returning a new list containing all the items that exist in both lists:

```
lst3 = list1.Union(lst2).OrderBy(p=>p).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach (I think the most effcient one [amortized]):

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(lst1);
foreach (var item in lst2) 
{
    hashSet.Add(item);
}

var lst3 = hashSet.ToList();
```

LINQ:

```
var lst3 = lst1.Union(lst2).ToList();
```

Comment: `Union` already removes the duplicates, no need for `Distinct`

Answer (score 2):

You can use UNION and fetch DISTINCT values from resultset

```
lst3 = lst1.Union(lst2).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A basic approach

```
        List<int> lst3 = new List<int>();
        foreach (int x in lst1)
            if (!lst3.Contains(x))
                lst3.Add(x);
        foreach (int x in lst2)
            if (!lst3.Contains(x))
                lst3.Add(x);
```

Comment: Your answer probably got down-voted because the OP asked for a LINQ solution.