# Nicer Way to Get Distinct Values From Two Fields

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects.  This object contains two id fields.  I want to create a distinct list of ids from both these id fields.

Here is my code

```
IList<Data> model;
...
var userIds = model.Select(_ => _.FromUserId).ToList();
userIds.AddRange(model.Select(_ => _.ToUserId));
userIds = userIds.Distinct().ToList();
```

This seems awfully long-winded and horrible.  Is there a better way?

Comment: `model.Select(_ => _.FromUserId).Union(model.Select(_ => _.ToUserId)).ToList();` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201952/selecting-distinct-elements-from-two-lists-using-linq/26201980 includes all these solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create a list of both the user IDs from the model and then flatten this list using [`SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0). It does both the projection and flattening for you in one call.

```
model.SelectMany(data => new List<UserIdType> { data.FromUserId, data.ToUserId })
     .Distinct()
     .ToList()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the shortest I can think of:

```cs
var models = new List<(int FromUserId, int ToUserId)>();
...
var userIds = models
   .SelectMany(m => new[] { m.FromUserId, m.ToUserId })
   .Distinct()
   .ToList();
```

Comment: `new List<(int FromUserId, int ToUserId)>()` compiles?

Comment: Yeah sure, it's a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples).

Comment: Good solution, I ran this code against Amal & Peter B suggestions. This was the best performance wise (using BenchmarkDotNet) Your's = `163.1 ns` Amal = `174.8 ns` and Peters = `232.1 ns`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is very readable + pretty short, and possibly also the most efficient depending on the actual datatype (example code assumes `string` for the `xxUserId` datatype):

```
var h = new HashSet<string>();
h.UnionWith(model.Select(x => x.FromUserId));
h.UnionWith(model.Select(x => x.ToUserId));
var userIds = h.ToList();
```

Or moving the first `Select` into the `HashSet` constructor call:

```
var h = new HashSet<string>(model.Select(x => x.FromUserId));
h.UnionWith(model.Select(x => x.ToUserId));
var userIds = h.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned by @Selvin in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68410481/nicer-way-to-get-distinct-values-from-two-fields/68410915#comment120902231_68410481), you can use `.Union` to get the two lists together

```cs
model.Select(_ => _.FromUserId)
  .Union(
    model.Select(_ => _.ToUserId)
).ToList();
```

Alternatively, if you want to concatenate without ensuring distinct results:

```cs
model.Select(_ => _.FromUserId)
  .Concat(
    model.Select(_ => _.ToUserId)
).ToList();
```